# notify Q Promise progress in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I wanted to use `Q` `Promise` Progress functionality, I have this code and i want to catch progress and when progress is 100, then resolve the `Promise`:

```
var q = require("q");

var a =  function(){
    return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify){
        var percentage = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            percentage += 20;
            notify(percentage);
            if (percentage === 100) {
                resolve("a");
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 500);
    });
};

var master = a();

master.then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
})

.then(function(progress){
    console.log(progress);
});
```

But i get this error:

```
Error: Estimate values should be a number of miliseconds in the future
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this error, if i try to run your script (node 4.2.1), but you never listen to the progress of the promise.
You need to register the progressHandler as third parameter to the `.then` function:

```
var q = require("q");

var a =  function(){
    return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify){
        var percentage = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            percentage += 20;                
            notify(percentage);
            if (percentage === 100) {
                resolve("a");
                clearInterval(interval);
           }
        }, 500);
    });
};

function errorHandler(err) {
  console.log('Error Handler:', err);
}

var master = a();

master.then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}, 
errorHandler,
function(progress){
    console.log(progress);
});
```

Output:

```
20
40
60
80
100
a
```

You must register the progress callback as third parameter to the `.then`-function or you can use the special `.progress()` shorthand, see https://github.com/kriskowal/q#progress-notification

Here is the call chain with the `progress` shorthand:

```
var master = a();
master.progress(function(progress{
    console.log(progress)})
.then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

In your code, console.log(progress) prints `undefined`, because the function is listen to the result of the previous `.then`-statement, which returns nothing.

Comment: if i use one error handler for multiple promises, this should work? right now you are saying if an specific promise throws to error, an error handler function fires

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify this point a little bit further.

Comment: it seems progress is deprecated: https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseprogressonprogress

Comment: @Fcoder — only `.observeEstimate` is. `.progress()` is still part, even of [the introduction](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#progress-notification).